# MongoDB populate returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to populate my user schema with items but for some reason it does not populate anything in to the user schema. Could someone please take a look. I have 1 user and 1 item belonging to that user within my database but nothing is populating and I keep seeing null.

User Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    discordID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    discordImage: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    items: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
    }]
})

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Item Schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")

var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    purchasedPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    purchasedDate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    }
})

const Item = module.exports = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema)
```

Populate Code

```
app.get("/inventory", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await req.user.populate({
            path: 'items'
        }).execPopulate()
        console.log(req.user)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    res.status(200).render("inventory.ejs", { currentUser: req.user })
})
```

Objects in the DB:

Item:

[image]

User:

[image]

Comment: I've also tried populate with 'req.user.populate("items")" to no avail

Comment: Step 1, without populate, if you log your user.items is there any object-id's in there, like so: `[ ObjectId("5ecf2a3a8d72565ff0081e66") ]`?

Comment: no its just empty

Answer (score 0):

Used virtual method on user schema to create association

```
userSchema.virtual("items", {
    ref: "Item",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "author"
})
```

Worked fine with original code

Answer (score -1):

> I keep seeing null.

and

> no its just empty

hints there are no items added to your user. You need to have some ids you can populate.

All populate does is convert an ObjectID into a document. **There is no magic that will sync `itemSchema.author` with `userSchema.items`.**

Hence, it's not enough to add the author to the item. You also need to add the item to the author.

So for example, you could add an item like this:

```
const item = new Item({author: user._id});
await item.save();
req.user.items.push( item );
await req.user.save();
```

Now when you log req.user, are there any items there?

Once you see objectIds, then you can go back and add that `.populate('items')` into the mix and I promise you it'll work.